# Best way to get rid of old messages/posts in a collection?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I know this website prefers answers over discussions but I am quite lost on this.
What would be a sufficient enough way to get rid of old messages that are stored in a collection? As they are messages, there will be a large amount of them.

What I have so far are either deleting messages using

```
if (Messages.find().count() > 100) {
    Messages.remove({
        _id: Messages.findOne({}, { sort: { createdAt: 1 } })._id
    });
}
```

and I have also tried using expire.

Is there any other/more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you define the age to expiry, there are two ways you can go about this.

The first one would be to use ["TTL indexes"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/) that automatically prune some collections based on time. For instance, you might have a logs table to log all the application events and you only want to keep the logs for the last hour. To implement this, add a date field to your logs document. This will indicate the age of the document. MongoDB will use this field to determine if your document is expired and needs to be removed:

```
db.log_events.insert({
   "name": "another log entry"
   "createdAt": new Date()
})
```

Now add a TTL index to your collection on this field. In the example below I used an `expireAfterSeconds` value of 3600 which will annihilate logs after every hour:

```
db.log_events.createIndex({ "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 })
```

So for your case you would need to define an appropriate expiry time in seconds. For more details refer to the MongoDB documentation on [expiration of data using TTL indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/).

---

The second approach involves manually removing the documents based on a date range query. For the example above given the same collection, to remove documents older that an hour you need to create a date that represents an hour ago relative to the current timestamp and use that date as the query in the remove method of the collection:

```
var now = new Date(),
    hourAgo = new Date(now.getTime() - (60 * 60 * 1000));

db.log_events.remove({"createdAt": { "$lte": hourAgo }})
```

The above will delete log documents older than an hour.